# Como excluir observações E variáveis numa matriz no R?

Tags: r

A situação é a seguinte: eu tenho uma matriz com 271 observações e 14 variáveis no R. Preciso excluir aleatoriamente um determinado número de cruzamentos e variáveis, mantendo a ordem dos cruzamentos remanescentes e adicionando NA's nos cruzamentos excluídos.

No presente momento, eu consigo excluir e substituir aleatoriamente as observações ("linhas" ou "rows"), usando o seguinte código:

```
X100amostra <- X100[sample(1:nrow(X100), 50,
   replace=TRUE),]
```

onde "50" é o número de exclusões aleatórias.

Ainda, eu consigo fazer exclusões na forma de vetores. Eu gostaria de fazer na forma de matriz.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é isso que você quer:

```
matriz<- matrix(1:3794,ncol=14) # Cria uma matriz qualquer 271x14
matriz[sample(1:length(matriz),50,replace=FALSE)]<-NA # Substitui 50 valores por NA aleatoriamente
```